# Hadoop Java Error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.packt.ch3.etl.ParseWeblogs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, data-processing

I am new to Hadoop.I followed some tutorials and tried running the example in my hadoop cluster whose version is 2.7.0, unfortunately I got the errors as below:

```
$ javac *.java

$ jar cvf myjar.jar *.class

$ hadoop jar ./myjar.jar com.packt.ch3.etl.ParseWeblogs /user/hadoop/apache_clf.txt /user/hadoop/apache_clf_tsv


        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.packt.ch3.etl.ParseWeblogs
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

My classpath was set as below:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$ANT_HOME/lib/ant-launcher.jar

export CLASSPATH="/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:$CLASSPATH"
```

And source code of file ParseWeblogs.java listed as below:

```
        package com.packt.ch3.etl;

        import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
        import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
        import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
        import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
        import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
        import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;


        public class ParseWeblogs extends Configured implements Tool {

            public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

                Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
                Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

                Configuration conf = getConf();
                Job weblogJob = new Job(conf, "ParseWeblogs");
            //weblogJob.setJarByClass(ParseWeblogs.class);
                weblogJob.setJobName("Weblog Transformer");
                weblogJob.setJarByClass(getClass());
                weblogJob.setNumReduceTasks(0);
                weblogJob.setMapperClass(CLFMapper.class);        
                weblogJob.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                weblogJob.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
                weblogJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                weblogJob.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
                weblogJob.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
                weblogJob.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

            //weblogJob.setJarByClass(ParseWeblogs.class);

                FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(weblogJob, inputPath);
                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(weblogJob, outputPath);


                if(weblogJob.waitForCompletion(true)) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return 1;
            }

            public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
                int returnCode = ToolRunner.run(new ParseWeblogs(), args);
                System.exit(returnCode);
            }

        }

    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Source code of file CLFMapper.java listed as below:

```
    package com.packt.ch3.etl;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


    public class CLFMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = 
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z");
        private Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([\\d.]+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] \"(\\w+) (.+?) (.+?)\" (\\d+) (\\d+) \"([^\"]+|(.+?))\" \"([^\"]+|(.+?))\"", Pattern.DOTALL);

        private Text outputKey = new Text();
        private Text outputValue = new Text();
        @Override
        protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String entry = value.toString();
            Matcher m = p.matcher(entry);
            if (!m.matches()) {
                return;
            }
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = dateFormatter.parse(m.group(4));
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                return;
            }
            outputKey.set(m.group(1)); //ip
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            b.append(date.getTime()); //timestamp
            b.append('\t');
            b.append(m.group(6)); //page
            b.append('\t');
            b.append(m.group(8)); //http status
            b.append('\t');
            b.append(m.group(9)); //bytes
            b.append('\t');
            b.append(m.group(12)); //useragent
            outputValue.set(b.toString());
            context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
        }

    }
```

Could anyone help me please, I tried several solutions but cannot figure it out yet. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Certainly you do not have the dependency in the classpath/build path. It would also help adding info what you tried and problem with that.

Comment: I executed programs as below:
$ export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$ANT_HOME/lib/ant-launcher.jar;export CLASSPATH="/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:$CLASSPATH" 
$ javac *.java;jar cvf myjar.jar *.class;hadoop jar ./myjar.jar com.packt.ch3.etl.ParseWeblogs /user/hadoop/apache_clf.txt /user/hadoop/apache_clf_tsv  I got the errors mentioned as previous but WordCount works

Comment: @rocky : I doubt if your jar is not properly created as wordcount works properly.

Comment: @rocky: Where you created your code. eclipse? If eclipse create jar from there itself

Comment: @Unmesha SreeVeni: I created my jar using linux commands such as javac and jar command instead of eclipse as mentioned before, please see my descriptions before,thanks.

Comment: @Unmesha SreeVeni:  Both the method of creating jar of wordcount and the other jar are the same, while unfortunately the other jar doesn't work.

Comment: @Rao: Please see my details mentioned above,thanks a lot.

Comment: @rocky: Could you please uncomment this weblogJob.setJarByClass(ParseWeblogs.class); and create jar and see whether it works?Comment weblogJob.setJarByClass(getClass());

Comment: @Unmesha SreeVeni: it cannot work either  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try with this Driver class.
I made few edits.
Lets see if it works or not.

```
package trail;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class ParseWeblogs extends Configured implements Tool {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        try {
            int res = ToolRunner.run(conf, new ParseWeblogs(), args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int run(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        /*
         * Arguments
         */
        String source = args[0];
        String dest = args[1];
        FileSystem fs = null;
        try {
            fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Path in = new Path(source);
        Path out = new Path(dest);

        Job weblogJob = null;
        try {
            weblogJob = new Job(conf, "ParseWeblogs");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        weblogJob.setJarByClass(ParseWeblogs.class);
        weblogJob.setMapperClass(CLFMapper.class);
        weblogJob.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        weblogJob.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        weblogJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        weblogJob.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        try {
            TextInputFormat.addInputPath(weblogJob, in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
         * Delete output dir if exist
         */
        try {
            if (fs.exists(out)) {
                fs.delete(out, true);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(weblogJob, out);
        boolean success = false ;
        try {
            success = weblogJob.waitForCompletion(true);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return success ?0:1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doens't work.     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.packt.ch3.etl.ParseWeblogs
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Comment: :( why is it so. Ok let me run in my cluster

Comment: Thanks a lot, and could you please let me know the results later? Thanks in advance.

Comment: some other name..try to rename your package as trail or some thing else..[Naming convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

Comment: Yeah,understood!  I removed the package and it works. So I am wandering the advantage and usage of package in java. Could you please explained it or proviede me some useful references? Thanks very much!

Comment: [Naming a Package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

Comment: Edited my answer with different package name. Please accept the answer.

Comment: I wanna accept your answer 15 mins ago sorry but I don't know how to operate it on stackoverflow since it is my frist time to ask questions here, maybe you could kindly tell me how to do it. thanks. Besides, I found the job could run on hadoop cluster, but the result file of the job is empty, I am working on it.

Comment: :) oh empty. ok fine let me know if u need further help

Comment: Hi Unmesha, I figured out the problems, and it works, all the results are correct :-)